# Symfony Routing annotation not recognized

Tags: symfony, routes

I have declared the following in routing.yml file:

```
AcmeFrontendBundle:
  resource: "@AcmeFrontendBundle/Controller"
  type: annotation
```

Then I am calling it in the controller like this (this one works):

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
....
class ArticleVariantController extends Controller
{ 
....
/**
* Set delete status to an image
* @Route("/article-variant/soft-delete-image-ajax/{id}", name="acme_frontend_article_variant_soft_delete_image")
* @Method({"POST"})
*
* @param integer $id Article Erp Id
* @return mixed
*/
public function softDeleteImageAjaxAction($id)
{
    return $this->deleteImageHandler($id);
}
```

But this one does not get recognized as a route (only if I add it in the routing.yml file - which I don't want to do):

```
/*
* Deactivate article variant
* @Route("/article-variant/deactivate-article-variant-ajax/{id}", name="acme_frontend_deactivate_article_variant_ajax")
* @Method({"POST"})
*
* @param integer $id article Id
* @return mixed
*/
public function deactivateArticleVariantAjaxAction($id)
{
   return $this->articleVariantsHandler($id);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: do you have ``use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route`` at the top of the class?

Comment: Maybe you need to clear your cache?

Comment: @TomaszMadeyski I am using it. Michael I cleared it several times

Comment: Try running `router:debug` and seeing if those routes are present...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the PHPDoc Declaration...

It was like this:

```
/*
* Deactivate article variant
* @Route("/article-variant/deactivate-article-variant-ajax/{id}", name="acme_frontend_deactivate_article_variant_ajax")
* @Method({"POST"})
*
* @param integer $id article Id
* @return mixed
*/
```

and it should be like this note the second star in the begining of the comment

```
/** <- this one here!
* Deactivate article variant
* @Route("/article-variant/deactivate-article-variant-ajax/{id}", name="acme_frontend_deactivate_article_variant_ajax")
* @Method({"POST"})
*
* @param integer $id article Id
* @return mixed
*/
```

Using the PHPStorm shortcuts /* ctrl+enter... should be /** ctrl+enter not to have it as a comment `/* ... */` but as a PHPDoc declaration.